# How to disable Mysql replication logs?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a setup in which there is database replication from 1 machine X to another machine Y.
The problem is that MySql replication logs i.e.

master-bin.xyz and slave-relay.xyz

becomes too large and endup taking entire diskspace.

How to disable this logs?

Comment: You can't disable the logs -- they are critical for replication.  You can limit their size and automatically rotate and purge them, however...

Answer (score 0):

Without binary logs, replication is not possible.

However, you can set a size limit for each log with...

```
 max_binlog_size=50M
```

You can also set the logs to expire to save drive space with...

```
expire_logs_days=7
```

Of course these are settings for my server. You'll have to figure out what is best for your server.