# bitnami /opt/bitnami/mysql/data increases in size over time

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I'm having a similar issue as to what is described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323407/bitnami-opt-bitnami-mysql-data-increases-in-size-by-itself/334409) which never received an answer.

I'm running bitnami and my server space is filling up over time on what is a very simple static website.

I narrowed the cluprit down to the /opt/bitnami/mysql/data folder which seems to be increasing in size at a rate of about 158KB per minute (aka 230MB per day).

Some potentially relevant (or irrelevant) info I noticed: Running `sudo du -b` yields the following

> 10553149373 ./data

but running `ls -l` yields the following

> drwxr-x--- 7 mysql root 12288 Dec 25 06:25 data

The size of the data folder is stationary in the case of the ls command as each time I run that I get the same output. But the du command shows that the size is growing. And note the size difference between the two (I understand that du shows allocated space and ls shows actual usage. Why would one be so much bigger than the other - and why does du show it growing while ls does not).

Comment: `ls` shows the size of a single node in the directory hierarchy. In the case of a single file, it's the number of bytes in the file. In the case of a directory, it's the size of the storage used to hold directory entries. _Not_ the files contained within that directory.

Comment: Somewhere in that directory tree you'll find one or more large files. One way to find them is with `find data -ls`, then sorting the output by the size field (use `sort -n`). They could correspond to tables, or they may be other files used internally by MySQL. Edit your question with the pathnames of the largest files (although it's really not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, since it's not programming-related).

Comment: Thanks! It seems "518712  973412 -rw-r-----   1 mysql    mysql     996765731 Dec 30 04:59 data/binlog.000111" is the culprit. It appears to be a binary log. How do I stop this file from growing or eating up space? Is there any underlying problem which is causing it to grow? I never had a problem before so not sure why it grows all of a sudden? Should I stop binary logging? Or would that be treating the symptom and not the cause?

Comment: Binlog files are used for replication (and, iirc, only for replication). Normally they're deleted after being read, and there are configuration options to delete old files whether or not they've been read. It's been a long time since I've worked with MySQL, so can't give you any advice. You can read the [Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) section of the manual, but unless you're familiar with how your MySQL database is set up you might cause damage. I recommend finding a local MySQL expert who can help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Do you have only a single node with no replication? Using the default cnf file or providing your own?

Comment: @gusto2 I am running a single instance on AWS, not replication to my knowledge. I am also using the defaults.

Comment: I suggest you copy and review the my.cnf file from the docker container and disable the log or limit its size
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033101/how-to-disable-mysql-replication-logs